# How to send some flag while including child component in Parent Component,so that It will chose proper sightly template?

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I include 5 child component resources in Parent component .I am using(calling) two slightly templates in my child component based on condition. Is there any way to add some flag while including child resource so that it will call the appropriate sightly template while rendering.

this is the code for including child component.

```
<div class="item one" data-sly-resource="${'item1' @ resourceType='example/core/components/CategoryItem'}" data-sly-unwrap></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [selectors](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#229-resource) to specify which HTL/Sightly script you want to render your resource.

Assuming a structure of your component like:

```
/apps/example/categoryitem
+- categoryitem.html
+- alternate.html
```

you can invoke either of the two scripts by including your resource with:

```
data-sly-resource="${item1 @ resourceType='example/categoryitem'}"
```

to call the default script, or

```
data-sly-resource="${item1 @ resourceType='example/categoryitem', selectors='alternate'}"
```

to call the alternate script